# force:recordData not loading any data

Tags: lightning, lightning-data-service

I'm trying to load data using Lightning Data Service with force:recordData, but i'm not seeing any data is being displayed.

Below is the code for the same. Can you someone help me where I'm doing the mistake.

**CarDetails component**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <aura:attribute type="Id" name="Id" access="public" />
    <aura:attribute type="Car__c" name="car" access="public" />
    <aura:attribute name="recordError" type="String" access="private" />

    <aura:handler event="c:CarSelectedApplicationEvent" action="{!c.onCarSelected}" />

    <!-- using lightning data service to fetch record data
        * recordUpdated="{!c.onRecordUpdated}" is optional
        and use it only if you need to fire an event on update
        *mode can be either edit or view-->
    <force:recordData aura:id="service"
                      recordId="{!v.Id}"
                      mode="VIEW"
                      targetFields="{!v.car}"
                      targetError="{!v.recordError}"
                      recordUpdated="{!c.onRecordUpdated}"
                      fields="Id, Name, Mileage__c, Per_Day_Rent__c, Build_Year__c, 
                              Contact__r.Name, Contact__r.Email, Contact__r.HomePhone__c,
                              Car_Type__r.Name, Picture__c" />

    <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
        <lightning:layoutItem size="12" 
                      smallDeviceSize="12" 
                      mediumDeviceSize="12" 
                      largeDeviceSize="12">
            <aura:if isTrue="{!empty(v.car)}">
                <lightning:tabset aura:id="tabs">
                    <lightning:tab label="Details" id="cardetailtab">
                        Car {!v.car.Name} will be shown here
                        <c:CarDetail car="{!v.car}"/>
                    </lightning:tab>
                </lightning:tabset>
            </aura:if>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
    </lightning:layout>

</aura:component>
```

**CarDetailsController.js**

```
({
    onRecordUpdated : function(component, event, helper) {

    },
    onCarSelected : function(component, event, helper){
        component.set("v.Id",event.getParam("car").Id);
        console.log("carId--"+event.getParam("car").Id);
        component.find("service").reloadRecord();
    }
})
```

**CarSelectedApplicationEvent**

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION" description="Event template">
    <aura:attribute name="car" type="Car__c" />
</aura:event>
```

**CarDetail**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
<aura:attribute type="Car__c" name="car" access="public" 
                default="{
                         'Name' : 'My Default Car',
                         'Contact__r' : {
                                            'Name':'Default Contact'
                                        },
                         'Car_Type__c' : {
                                            'Name':'Default Car Type'
                                        },
                         'Build_Year__c' : 2000,
                         'Per_Day_Rent__c' : 100,
                         'Mileage__c' : 15,
                         'Picture__c' : '/resource/cars/luxury/ford_Mustang.jpeg'
                         }" />
<aura:attribute type="boolean" name="showCardAction" access="public" default="false" />

<aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}" />

<lightning:card iconName="utility:setup_assistant_guide">    
    <aura:set attribute="title">        
        <lightning:formattedText value="{!v.car.Contact__r.Name + '\'s Car'}" />        
    </aura:set>
    <aura:set attribute="actions">
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showCardAction}">
            <lightning:button variant="neutral" label="Full Details" onclick="{!c.onFullDetails}" />
        </aura:if>
    </aura:set>

    <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
        <lightning:layoutItem size="12" smallDeviceSize="6" mediumDeviceSize="6" largeDeviceSize="6"
                              flexibility="true">
            <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small">
                <div class="carproperty">
                    <span class="label">Car Name:</span>
                    <lightning:formattedText value="{!v.car.Name}" />
                </div>
                <div class="carproperty">
                    <span class="label">Type:</span>
                    <lightning:formattedText value="{!v.car.Car_Type__r.Name}" />
                </div>
                <div class="carproperty">
                    <span class="label">Build Year:</span>
                    <lightning:formattedNumber value="{!v.car.Build_Year__c}" />
                </div>
                <div class="carproperty">
                    <span class="label">Per Day Rent:</span>
                    <lightning:formattedNumber value="{!v.car.Per_Day_Rent__c}" 
                                             style="currency" currencyCode="USD"/>
                </div>
                <div class="carproperty">
                    <span class="label">Mileage:</span>
                    <lightning:formattedNumber value="{!v.car.Mileage__c}" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
        <lightning:layoutItem size="12" smallDeviceSize="6" mediumDeviceSize="6" largeDeviceSize="6"
                              flexibility="true">
            <div class="imageview" style="{!'background-image:url(' + v.car.Picture__c + ')'}" />
        </lightning:layoutItem>
    </lightning:layout>        
</lightning:card>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**added based on comments:**

You will get no data if any of your field APIs in `fields` is wrong.

For identifying this, you use only Id and Name initially:

```
fields="Id, Name"
```

and remove all other fields and its references anywhere else in code and just use Id and Name

---

According to your implementation in `isTrue="{!empty(v.car)}"`, you are saying you want to render the content only when `v.car` is empty. Instead it should be `isTrue="{!not(empty(v.car))}"`

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.car))}">
    <lightning:tabset aura:id="tabs">
        <lightning:tab label="Details" id="cardetailtab">
            Car {!v.car.Name} will be shown here
            <c:CarDetail car="{!v.car}"/>
        </lightning:tab>
    </lightning:tabset>
</aura:if>
```

**added based on comments:**

Or else you can have like below to render something before record loads:

```
<lightning:tabset aura:id="tabs">
    <lightning:tab label="Details" id="cardetailtab">
        <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.car))}">
            Car {!v.car.Name} will be shown here
            <c:CarDetail car="{!v.car}"/>
        </aura:if>
    </lightning:tab>
</lightning:tabset>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for ur reply. when I set it to not(empty(v.car)) the entire section is not coming up as that is null. so for time being i had it like that.

Comment: added in answer. So, the error is gone now?

Comment: There is no error comping up. From the attached screenshot above, when I add not(empty(v.car)) instead of empty(v.car), then I'm not seeing anything from there as v.car is becoming empty.

Comment: Tried moving the aura:if to inside the lightning:tab still same.

Comment: My concern is, somewhere it is messing up here I guess. as the v.car is Null

<force:recordData aura:id="service"
                      recordId="{!v.Id}"
                      mode="VIEW"
                      targetFields="{!v.car}"
                      targetError="{!v.recordError}"
                      recordUpdated="{!c.onRecordUpdated}"
                      fields="Id, Name, Mileage__c, Per_Day_Rent__c, Build_Year__c, 
                              Contact__r.Name, Contact__r.Email, Contact__r.HomePhone__c,
                              Car_Type__r.Name, Picture__c" />

Comment: are you getting log ---- `console.log("carId--"+event.getParam("car").Id);` ?

Comment: Yes. the Id is coming in the console log

Comment: check answer in starting

Comment: Thank you so much. it worked. Issue is with the list of fields added as you said.